# Maven/Netbeans Have different testing profiles and environment variables

Tags: java, testing, maven, netbeans, selenium

We are trying to do Selenium tests for our java web application.  We would like to be able to quickly configure our tests with a combination of the java function "System.getProperty" and modifying the profiles available for the test.

The reason for doing this is so that we can test different servers with a simple change of the dropdown box in netbeans (from < default config > to "server name/details"). Our servers run things like a Snapshot, RC, and hotfix branch so this would be very helpful in tracking down when bugs are introduced.

Our current method for doing this is modifying the test variables before each run to target the server we want (yuck!).

Any thoughts would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

The simplest mechanism might well be to create [profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) in your POM that are activated by a system property or environment variable.

An example from the Maven documentation (with small modifications for clarity):

```xml
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <activation>
      <property>
        <name>myProperty</name>
        <value>test</value>
      </property>
    </activation>
    ...
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

Which you'd activate manually with:

```
mvn groupId:artifactId:goal -DmyProperty=test
```

You'd enable this based on an environment variable by using the fact that Maven maps environment vars into properties with the name `env.…` (with case normalization on Windows):

```xml
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <activation>
      <property>
        <name>env.ENVIRONMENT</name>
        <value>test</value>
      </property>
    </activation>
    ...
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

Which you'd activate with:

```bash
export ENVIRONMENT=test  # Does not need to be done every build, just per session
mvn groupId:artifactId:goal
```